# Event Aggregator.. not getting a response, how to determine completion?

Tags: design, design-patterns, javascript

I'm rewriting a vehicle tracking application, a google maps based thing..

The users are able to search for a vehicle by typing a few characters of the vehicles "callsign".

My application is based around a sort of "event bus" within Backbone.. when a search occurs I send a message on the bus saying something like "does anyone match this?".. If a marker matches the search term it responds with a sort of "yes, I match!"..

My challenge arises when no-one matches, I get no response.. it feels a little hacky to "wait a little while" and check if a response has been recieved..

The application is based around Backbone.js and using the Event Aggregator pattern described in the answer to this question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708195/access-function-in-one-view-from-another-in-backbone-js

Is there a well defined design pattern that might assist me here? Sending a request for a response and not getting any responses?

Comment: not a pattern, but design principle (that worked great for me in cases like that): _expiration by timeout_ should be first class citizen in your application. Designed and carefully thought out from the scratch, easy to use by developers, easy to maintain by supporters (configuration, logging, audit trail...) and easy to understand by end users: _"no response from vehicle in 5 minutes, timeout expired. Retry, cancel?"_

Answer (score 1):

Could they not all reply with a NoResultFound message?

You know how many domains you have, so if they all reply with NoResultFound, then you'll know what to do.

I guess this depends on the UI that you have. Assuming your UI has a list of search domains, then once the result comes back from each domain, you can display it to the user:

- DomainA - Searching...
- DomainB - No Results Found
- DomainC - Searching...
- DomainD - No Results Found
- etc